# How can I fix the build fail of Android Studio : sdklib.jar not found

Tags: android, build, ide, android-studio

I got the error even when I build a newly created project!! I have already installed all SDKs I need. SDK path setting seems all correct. I have even re-installed Android Studio. Please help.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:classpath'.
   > Could not download artifact 'com.android.tools:sdklib:22.4.2:sdklib.jar'
      > Artifact 'com.android.tools:sdklib:22.4.2:sdklib.jar' not found.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

Answer (score 0):

Open up android sdk and try updating ur adb and platform tools if available and also download the platform stuff is something is missing,  eg if you are developing something with target 4.1 and min 2.3.3 then u shud download everything that can be downloaded from sdk within respective drop down list in sdk manager